# Object in class set as variable

Tags: javascript

Here is my javascript:

```
var error_msg = error_data.validation_msg;
if(error_msg)
{
     for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
     {
          var answer_exact = 'answer_exact_'+i;
          var error = error_msg.answer_exact;
     }         
}
```

How I can call objects in error_msg class like:

```
error_msg.answer_exact_0;
error_msg.answer_exact_1;
error_msg.answer_exact_2;
....
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to get a property using a dynamic key(where the property name is stored in a variable).

```
var error = error_msg[answer_exact];
```

Your code tries to read a property named `answer_exact` from the object `error_msg`